# Extending a bounded linear operator of finite rank

Tags: functional-analysis, duality-theorems

Let $X$ and $Y$ be normed spaces and let $W$ be a subspace of $X$. Assume that $T$ is a bounded linear operator from $W$ to $Y$, that is of finite rank. Show that $T$ can be extended to a bounded linear operator $T'$ from $X$ to $Y$ such that $T'(X) = T(W)$.

I think the Hahn-Banach extension theorem is needed somewhere, but since that theorem deals with extensions of functionals, i have no idea where to go..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Say $b_1,\dots,b_n$ is a basis for the finite-dimensional space $T(W)$. Let $a_1,\dots,a_n:T(W)\to\Bbb F$ be the coordinate functionals: $$v=\sum_1^na_j(v)b_j\quad(v\in T(W)).$$Note that $a_j$ is bounded, since $T(W)$ has finite dimension.

So $a_j\circ T:W\to\Bbb F$ is bounded; let $\alpha_j:X\to\Bbb F$ be a bounded linear extension of $a_j\circ T$. Define $S:X\to Y$ by $$Sx=\sum_1^n \alpha_j(x)b_j.$$Then $S$ is linear and bounded, and  if $w\in W$ then
$$Tw=\sum a_j(Tw)b_j=\sum\alpha_j(w)b_j=Sw.$$

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. I think i'm in the right direction now, but i'm not really sure about it.

Comment: Well think about it some - what I wrote is really a _big_ hint...

Comment: So $a_j = \Lambda_jw$. This is a bounded linear function to $\mathbb{F}$, so there exists an extension $\Lambda'_j : X \to \mathbb{F}$ by Hahn-Banach for every $j$. Then define
$$T' \ : \ X \to T(W) \ : \ x \mapsto \sum_{j=1}^n\Lambda'_j(x)v_j.$$
This is a bounded linear operator from $X$ to $Y$, with $T'(X) = T(W)$.

Comment: Right. Note that $\Lambda_j$ is bounded by one of the inequalities in my answer, _plus_ the fact that $T$ is bounded...

Comment: It works. Thanks!

Comment: How $|\Lambda_j(w)|\leq c\|T(w)\|$?

Comment: @Anupam Any linear functoinal on a finte-dimensional space is bounded. $T(W)$ has finite dimension by hypothesis.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich $\Lambda_j$ is defined on $W$ and not on $T(W)$ !

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I think you should edit this and say that the functionals $\Lambda_j$ are defined on $T(W)$ and $a_j=\Lambda_j(Tw)$. Everything will work fine after that and we still get $|a_j|\leq c\|Tw\|$.